# XOR of rows and columns of 4x4 magic squares

Tags: combinatorics

An article by John Conway, Simon Norton, and Alex Ryba, “Frenicle’s 880 Magic Squares,” in Jennifer Beineke and Jason Rosenhouse, eds., The Mathematics of Various Entertaining Subjects, Vol. 2, 2017, chapter 5, reports the "Nimm0" property for 4x4 magic squares with numbers from 0 to 15, with sum constraint on the diagonals too:
the bitwise exclusive OR (XOR) of all the numbers in a row or column is always 0 (see also an example [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.futilitycloset.com/2018/06/14/the-nimm0-property/amp/)). This can be verified with an exhaustive test of all 880 squares.
At note 1 they say that a conceptual proof has been found by Friedrich Fitting and Oliviero Giordano Cassani independently.
However I am not able to find the proof on the web.
Somebody can share it here?
Or is able to rediscover it?

Comment: See my answer below. I'm not sure if this was the proof they were referring to or if the proof I gave is common, but it's what I came up with.

Comment: The Conway et al. paper gives a complete bibliographical reference for the Fitting paper. I'm sure you could get it from a library, through interlibrary loan (but I hope your German is up to scratch). Cassani & Conway published an article, Neumbering, The Mathematical Intelligencer 40(1) · July 2017 so maybe there's something in there. Cassani appears to be at Oxford.

Comment: @GerryMyerson problem is I am not an academic, so I was trying to find something online.

Comment: You don't have to be an academic to go to a library, mbjoe. Alternatively, you could try writing to Cassani at Oxford. It's just a question of how important it is for you to know.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R_i$ denote the sum of the numbers in row $i$, $i=1,2,3,4$. Then $R_1+R_2+R_3+R_4 = 0+\dots+15 = \frac{15\cdot 16}{2} = 8\cdot 15$. So each $R_i = 2\cdot 15 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$. Therefore, the last digit of the XOR sum of any row is $0$. Similarly with the columns.

Now we show that the 2nd to last digit of the XOR sum of any row or column is $0$. For $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, let $\overline{a}$ denote $a \pmod{2} \in \{0,1\}$ and $\tilde{a} = \frac{a-\overline{a}}{2}$. Let $\tilde{R_i}$ denote the sum of $\tilde{a}$ over the $a$ in row $i$. Then $\tilde{R_1}+\tilde{R_2}+\tilde{R_3}+\tilde{R_4} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{15\cdot 16}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{15} \overline{j} = 4\cdot 15 - 4$. Therefore, assuming each $\tilde{R_i}$ is the same (see below), we get that each $\tilde{R_i} = 14 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$.

Similarly, if we let $\overline{\overline{a}}$ denote $a\pmod{4} \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, $\tilde{\tilde{a}} = \frac{a-\overline{\overline{a}}}{4}$, and $\tilde{\tilde{R_i}} = \sum_{a \in R_i} \tilde{\tilde{a}}$, then $\sum_i \tilde{\tilde{R_i}} = \frac{1}{4}\frac{15\cdot 16}{2}-\frac{1}{4}24 = 24$, so assuming each $\tilde{\tilde{R_i}}$ is the same (see below), each $\tilde{\tilde{R_i}} = 6$, which is, once again, $0 \pmod{2}$.

Finally, making the $\pmod{8}$ analogues of the definitions made above, we get $\sum_i \tilde{\tilde{\tilde{R_i}}} = \frac{1}{8}\frac{15\cdot 16}{2}-\frac{1}{8}56 = 8$, so assuming each $\tilde{\tilde{\tilde{R_i}}}$ is the same (see below), we get that each $\tilde{\tilde{\tilde{R_i}}} = 2$, which is $0 \pmod{2}$.

We have thus shown that the XOR sum of the numbers in any row or column is $0$.

---

Each $\tilde{R_i}$ is equal if and only if $\sum_{a \in R_i} \frac{a-\overline{a}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{a \in R_i} a - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{a \in R_i} \overline{a}$ is the same for each $i$, but since the $\sum_{a \in R_i} a$'s are equal, we just need the $\sum_{a \in R_i} \overline{a}$'s to be equal. In other words, we need the mod 2 of the magic square to be a magic square mod 2. It is well known that 4x4 magic squares indeed have this property.

Similarly for $\tilde{\tilde{R_i}}$ and $\tilde{\tilde{\tilde{R_i}}}$, an equivalent condition for them to be independent of $i$ is that the mod 4 (resp. 8) of the magic square is a magic square mod 4 (resp. 8). This is also well-known.

Comment: Just a very small fix on the second sentence: $R_1+R_2+R_3+R_4 = 0+\dots+15 = \frac{15\cdot 16}{2} = 8\cdot 15$. Also, could you give me a reference for the well-known $\mod 2$, $\mod 4$, $\mod 8$ property of magic squares? Thank you.

Comment: @mbjoe Fixed, thanks. And no I can't, sorry.

Comment: However that property is the core of the proof. Maybe it is in the Fitting's work.

Comment: We need the mod 2 magic square to be a magic square  , period. Not to be a magic square mod 2, because all squares including semi magic ones (for which diagonals don't give the same sum) have this property, but semi magic ones don't have the XOR property.

Comment: @mbjoe however you want to phrase it. I think what is needed for my answer to be complete is clear: a magic square has the property that $\tilde{R_i},\tilde{\tilde{R_i}},\tilde{\tilde{\tilde{R_i}}}$ are independent of $i$.

Comment: Ok +1. Please tell me if in future you find something about the $\tilde{R_i}$... property.

Comment: @mbjoe thanks. will do, I'll look out for it, cause I'm curious also

Answer (score 1):

The Conway et al. paper gives a complete bibliographical reference for the Fitting paper. I'm sure you could get it from a library, through interlibrary loan. Cassani & Conway published an article, Neumbering, The Mathematical Intelligencer 40(1) · July 2017 so maybe there's something in there. Cassani appears to be at Oxford, you could try to contact him.

Comment: The paper by Fitting is "Rein mathematische Behandlung des Problems der magischen Quadrate von 16 und von 64 Feldern," *Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereingung* 40 (1931), 177-199.